# SVN branch does not show on Drive

Tags: svn, version-control

I created a branch in `SVN` from my local computer by

- Right Click on SVNWorking Folder and
- Click `Branch/Tag`.

The branch seems to be created as in `SVN`, I can see the new branch `Base_F`. But on server I am not able to find this new branch. I check the repositories folder and other folders but didn't find the new branch. A previously created branch `Base_V` is visible on Drive. But this new branch is not visible. Can you please guide me how can I find this branch.

OR

Did I miss something during branch creation ?

[image]

Comment: I'm kind of lost with your references to right click and Git... What are the exact technologies this question is about?

Comment: @Álvaro González : sorry, it's not Git. I am using Tortise SVN. Git tag is mentioned by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You did WC to URL copy resulting in a new branch in the repository. Normally you should switch the working copy to the branch or checkout a new one. But since your working copy structure is wrong, i.e. it contains the whole repository with all branches and trunk, you have to run `svn update` to bring up the copies branch from the repository.

Don't forget that commits and updates in SVN are separate. And checkout a proper working copy that represents a branch or trunk. Don't use a working copy of the whole repository with all tags, branches and trunk. You can always switch between related branches instantly using `svn switch` command.

And don't forget to read the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/).

Comment: How should be its structure ? Can you please provide more details. Thank You